# Technical trends quietly aimed at big open problems?

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

When I was an undergraduate 35 years ago, I made the mistake of asking some of my mathematics professors what well-known open problems they liked to think about.  I got the message that this was something one did not discuss in polite society.  Perhaps the culture has changed?

This question asks mathematicians to "out" technical trends which (only) experts understand as lines of attack against well-known outstanding problems.

I suggest that answers take the form of a citation or two from the literature plus a statement or mere naming of the target open problem.  A few words additional about the philosophy underlying a given approach might also help, but I suggest allowing users to
submit further questions if they want copious details.

Please be careful not to "out" individual mathematicians, unless you are one.  Lots of mathematicians are really uncomfortable with their private tentative thoughts being made public.  The goal here is to "out" technical trends that are in the public record, but not widely known.  Alternately, if you are an expert in a famous open problem and want to out your own methods, feel free to do so.

Comment: Is your first sentence missing the word "famous" or "important" or "trendy" after the word "open"? After all, I spend most of my research time thinking about a bunch of open problems. They aren't ones that grab the headlines and inspire acolytes, but they are open (or else my skills at looking in the literature are failing me).

Comment: I am also not convinced that the point of the technical trends *is* to attack well-known outstanding problems - it could be that one is just trying to *understand* the constructs in question at a deeper level or in a more thorough way.

Comment: Mathematicians tend to be very cautious about endorsing lines of attack against well-known outstanding problems, because most of the time, these problems are so good at defending themselves that the attack is unsuccessful. 

Comment: Just to say that my comments were written before David added the example of Mazur's work/goal, which at least illustrates the kind of answer that is desired.

Comment: I see the votes to close piling up, but I do think that positive responses to this question might be useful to graduate students and others, and also attract attention to important research.

@Yemon - I chose "well-known" but "famous" or "important" would work too.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I don't think by any means that every technical trend falls under this category, but some definitely do.


Comment: David, in my opinion your question is too close to the area of gossiping. It seems  that the question asks people to repeat what mathematicians told them privately as is the Mazur's example. In this form I think it cannot be accepted

Comment: Closed.  I don't think MathOverflow should be a rumor mill.

Comment: Also, I strongly agree with Gil Kalai's second comment.

Comment: In light of a vote to reopen, meta thread opened here: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/854 Could whoever voted to re-open please comment on the meta thread, in the interests of debate etc

Comment: I've upvoted the question and I've also voted to reopen; the way I understand this question, it is not about rumors, it is about not-so-well-known approaches to well known problems. Meaningful answers to this would be of great benefit to everyone.

Comment: Algori echos my thoughts.  Thank you.  Not seeking rumors, rather experts pointing out the significance of published research that might otherwise remain obscure to the larger mathematical community.
  
The additional remarks I suggested might read "The authors prove... This is interesting because experts will see that if one could prove the stronger statement... it would have this impact... on this problem.  

At the implicit suggestion of Kalai and Carnahan, I have now removed my comparison to a specific well-establish social taboo.  
Thus their comments may now seem obscure.

Comment: David, the title, first, second, and fourth paragraphs make your question rather unclear. Am I right to understand that you do not refer to secret plans but to lines of attack towards central problems which are described explicitely in the literature and are not well known? (Perhaps because of technical difficulties.) And that you do not expect people to contribute personal knowledge or speculations on plans of others? Maybe you can formulate the question to express this intention and have a better example demonstrating it? (Also thanks for editing the question.) 

Comment: Gil,
I think your understanding of my intention is basically correct.  I do think that a received sense of decorum sometimes keeps authors from explicitly describing (in print) the ultimate aims of their research since their fellow experts (e.g. editors and referees) will understand anyway.  Thus some major work doesn't get the attention that it might, because folks just outside the circle don't recognize the motivation.  I have nothing against "art-for-art's sake" mathematics, but very goal oriented work can be confused for that, and it's interesting to know the difference.     

Comment: Gil (cont.), I don't think many authors, no matter how modest, would mind a third party broadcasting the potential significance of their work.  But if I could get the answers that I'm looking for without my question alluding to these culture issues, fine.  Could you suggest a wording that works for you?

Comment: David,  I think there may be various cases where people explicitely state their wildest motivations. If they don't then "outing" them may be delicate. For example, it is a difficult issue to what extent we want in MO experts giving their judgements on the works of others. If one expert describes a potential significance of a certain work, should we allow another expert to express a negative view? It is an uncharted territory for MO and I am not sure we want to go there. Another concerns is that the question is too wide. Even asking it for a single problem, say the RH, might be rather wide.

Comment: Dear David, Regarding Mazur, if you look at one of his joint papers with Tilouine written around the same time as his deformation theory paper, or at Fernando Gouvea's thesis also written at about the same time (Fernando was his student) then you would see that it was a matter of public record that his deformation theory was aimed at proving $R = T$ theorems, or at least stating them.  

Comment: Thanks Emerton,
You mean Représentations galoisiennes, différentielles de Kähler..?

OK, I take your point.  And of course no need to defend Mazur...I'm not accusing anyone of anything.  I still believe most professional mathematicians in 1990 and even many professional number theorists would not have easily spotted that work as progress towards FLT.

By contrast, I believe that few biologists whose work had any potential for the development of, say, a cancer therapy would want anyone to miss that aspect of their work.  (Certainly not when they're applying for funding).  Different culture.  

Comment: I have now removed my example, because I didn't want it to become a distraction, either on grounds of accuracy or etiquette.  Supports of this question, feel free to suggest a 24-karat, bullet proof example.  

Comment: There is a meta thread, why don't you lobby for your question there? See also http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/853/etiquette-proposal-one-meta-comment-per-user-per-post/

Comment: @Alex  Aside from just plain feeling a bit defeated, I believe that I just don't understand MO culture well enough to help my own case.  Even my echoing the comment of another suggesting that answers to my question will benefit many users of MO turned into proof prima facie that I didn't understand the mission of MO.  I still feel new here; the seasoned campaigners seems to regard MO as so very fragile that a question like mine could destroy the site.  I trust they have some history in mind that lies beyond my ken. 

Comment: David, my fear is not that it will "destroy the site". but that it is a question which it is easy for many people to give bad (i.e. ill-thought out) answers to, and as such will just lead to more heat than light. I don't understand why pub gossip/chatter is something which needs to be moved onto MO rather than left in the pub where I can enjoy it as such.

Comment: @Alex: that links to the wrong meta thread

Comment: Thanks for your remarks Yemon. First, I wrote the question in such a way to discourage ill-thought out answers: I asked for a citation to publications (in a field where the poster had expertise), together with the name or statement of a problem to which the paper turns out relevant, and perhaps a word of explanation. It seems to me that the site could maximize the light/heat ratio better by allowing the OP to delete weak or irrelevant answers than by preemptively preventing the best of the MO community from responding. Also, I think I don't have access to your pub... 

Comment: ...indeed I've never had access before or elsewhere to so many powerful mathematical minds at once.  I understand the desire to keep the site profession and technical, but even the Fields Medalists who contribute sometimes show the desire to explore issues less than purely cut and dry. Not all the work (work, not pub chatter) of a research mathematician consists in trying to solve specific problems.  Researchers also seek for new problems, attempt to synthesize the exponential amount of activity going on beyond their immediate ambient and try to absorb powerful viewpoints.

Comment: David, why not pose this problem for a single open problem that interest you the most?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Gil.  I don't think there is such a thing as a single open problem that interests me most.  My intellectual style is to read around a lot and look for ideas that might have analogs in a distant field; I wouldn't recommend my way of doing mathematics to a graduate student, but it has worked well enough for me.  So I guess really did ask the question I meant to ask for my own purposes and not for the general betterment of humanity after all (see the meta).

Comment: David, if "big open problems" refer to hundreds of potential problems in all areas of mathematics then this is a "huge list" problem which is much much too wide to be useful. (many mathematicians and many papers  implicitely or explicitely are geared towards solving important problems so answers to your question may cover a substantial percent of activity in mathematics.) If you mean only few very big and famous problems it makes more sense to ask about them one at a time. (And still think about analogs in a distant field.)

Comment: Gil, >David, if "big open problems" refer to hundreds of potential problems in all areas of mathematics

Well I only meant problems so "big" that a sense of decorum would prevent many mathematicians from openly announcing that they have such a problem in their sights or from explicitly bragging that their new result actually represents progress toward that goal.  Problems most or all serious mathematicians have heard of, regardless of specialty.  I can't put a number on it, but it feels like dozens not hundreds, and not many dozens at that.

Answer (score 0):

The study of L-functions is related to a few of the Millennium problems.

Comment: I guess this is not really quiet or secret.